# Formulas of basic modal logic involving only $\top$, $\bot$, propositional connectives and modalities

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am given a Kripke model $\mathcal{M}=(W, R, L)$ where $W=\{w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4\}$ $R=\{(w_1, w_2), (w_2, w_3), (w_4, w_1), (w_4, w_3)\}$, and for all $w \in W$, $L(w)=\varnothing$.

For each $w \in W$, I then want to find a basic modal formula that is only true at $w$. The formulas may only involve $\top$,$\bot$, and propositional connectives and modalities. The modalities that I have is necessity $\square$ and and possibility $\Diamond$.

I think that the formula $\square \bot$ is only true at $w_3$ since $w_3$ has no accessible worlds. But I am stuck finding formulas that are only true at the other worlds.

Comment: I think it is true, since for $\square\bot$ to be true, we require that $\bot$ is true for all accessible worlds. But since $w_3$ has no accessible worlds, $\square \bot$ is vacuously true.

Comment: Hint: now that you have a formula $\phi = \square \bot$ that is only true at $w_3$, you can append $\land \neg \phi$ to any other formula to make sure it is false at $w_3$ (and does not affect its truth at the other worlds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Continuing your approach, at what world(s) is $\square\square\bot$ true? What about $\square\square\square\bot$?

Now can you take Boolean combinations of these formulas and the one you found to isolate the individual worlds?